# how to use Spring JDBCTemplate for multiple DataSouce which is working together

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

We are using Spring JDBCTemplate for DataAccess. I have a spring mvc web application where user access the website and at the same time there are 4 quartz scheduler work behind and do some other processing with Database. Having multiple DataSource, and different threads(4 quartz scheduled and one web) works on different DataSource at a time, but while getting the getJDBCTemplate() it override the DataSource Context. What is the best way to manage this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest answer is probably to create several datasources, give each of them a different name, then wire them by name into the templates used by each client...  WIth annotations, it would be `@Autowired @Qualifier("dataSourceName1")` ...

Comment: the problem is that we are deciding the datasource  dynamically at run-time so not able to give static qualifier name...